# Deterministic Finite Automaton - Java

Tags: java, regex, boolean-logic

I need to create DFA which has alphabet: {a,b,c} & this alphabet accept words which first and last letter are different.
i.e.

"a" - is unacceptable

"ab" - is acceptable

"aaa bb" - is unacceptable

"cbba" - is acceptable

I'm trying firstly to check if there's an "a" at the beginning, but something is wrong, especially if I have i.o. "ab" or "ac" in file.txt.

Source:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Task
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt ")); 
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        wordList.add(line);
    }

    for (String word : wordList) 
    {
        if (word.matches("^a"))
        {   
            if (word.matches("ab") || word.matches("^ac"))
            {
                 System.out.print(word+" - OK\n");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(word+" - STOP (word doesn't exists in alphabet)\n");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What you do - a series of string matches, against the whole input words, does not really look like a DFA to me. 

To implement a DFA you should think in terms of "input signals","states" and "transitions" between those states .

Taking that your alphabet is defined as "a,b,c,{,},&", your code should be
accepting one of these chars at a time, and switch to the next state based on the current state and the input char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first "words.matches" will only match "**a**", if you want to match all word starting by a "**a**" then followed by something else you have to use "**^a.***", same for other matches.

Comment: Thanks - it works now. Can you tell me how can I stop the program on bad position? for example if I got in file: "abbc", I want to stop on "abb".

Comment: Fixing the regexes, won't turn this code into a DFA (which is the mission statement), moreover, it may trick OP into thinking that he has accomplished the task.